# why the phantomjs scraping code does not work?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

When I run `phantomjs filename.js` or `phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any filename.js`

I get: `status: fail` but the url indeed could be opened.

This is my code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
var system = require('system');
var u='https://sites.google.com/site/nurailcenter/research/nurail2012-uic-r06'
page.open(u, function(status){
    console.log("status: " + status);
    if(status === "success"){
        fs.write('result.html', page.content, 'w');
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: I just copy/pasted and ran the code.  I get `status: success`.

Comment: @Mr. Llama Thanks for your reply. What command line do you use?

Comment: It worked for both `phantomjs filename.js` and `phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any filename.js`.  Try a different URL to see if that works.  If it doesn't, you've got some system configuration issues that need to be addressed.

Comment: I tried other urls, it works. But on this one, it doesn't :( My phantomjs version is 2.0.0